# How to Setup a Scheme environment to use with Simply Scheme book?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am working through the book simply scheme (Harvey, Wright). I want to setup an environment that works well with the code in the book and is easy going for beginners.

Comment: look at DrRacket

Answer (score 3):

## Easiest in graphical environment:

I suggest you download and install [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/). Then when you have opened it install the simply-scheme package like this:

1. In the **File** menu choose **Package Manager**
2. In the initial tab you put `simply-scheme` in Package Source and press [Install]
3. Close the Package Manager window.

If you open **Racket documentation** in the **Help** menu it opens a local page and you will have the documentation for the newly installed language under "other language". Search for Simply and you'll find it. As a test it suggests you have this in the definitions window with *Determine language from source* in the select in the bottom left.

```scm
#lang simply-scheme

(se (butlast (bf "this"))
    "world")
; ==> (hi "world")
```

To start a program you press **[Run |>]**. When run you can do interactions in the same window as the REPL output or you can just add to definitions and run more times.

The IDE highlights your parentheses, ident your code according to convention such that you can realize your errors by pressing CTRL+i after heavy pasting. There is a debugger where you can step through your code and even a macroexpander. Christmas came early!

## Alternatives

From looking at the text it seems you can use just about any R5RS implementation with Simply Scheme and just have the `load` statements and files that come with the book. If graphical IDE is no your cup of tea there are [plenty of implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scheme_(programming_language)_implementations) that work under a shell (racket base included) and you can even use Emacs with many of them if that is your editor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) should do it.
Make sure to add

```
#lang racket
```

At the top of your file.